# Concatenate huge pictures

Tags: image-processing

I want to concatenate eight png-pictures each in the size of 21600px x 21600px in the form of 4 x 2 pictures using any program in windows. Trying ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick resulted in an error (due to a limitation of 65500px in any dimensions).
I also tried it with gimp, but it's too much for my computer (and gimp). I prefer a light program or even a command line program. Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

You could try [libvips](http://jcupitt.github.io/libvips/). It's a streaming image processing library -- it can decompress, process and recompress all at the same time -- so you only need enough memory for the small chunk of pixels actually being worked on.

You can join up your images from the command-line like this:

```
vips arrayjoin "1.png 2.png 3.png 4.png 5.png 6.png 7.png 8.png" x.png --across 4
```

And it'll make `x.png`, the result of joining up the 8 source images in a grid, with four images across. Images are laid out left-to-right and top-to-bottom, so you'll get:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

On this laptop, I see:

```
$ time vips arrayjoin "1.png 2.png 3.png 4.png 5.png 6.png 7.png 8.png" x.png --across 4
real    5m38.236s
user    7m9.735s
sys 0m2.851s
peak res 249mb
$ vipsheader x.png
x.png: 74976x37488 uchar, 3 bands, srgb, pngload
```

So it made a 70k x 40k pixel png in about five minutes and 250mb of memory. You'll find most of that time is spent in libpng compression -- tiff format would be at least three or four times faster.

On Windows, `arrayjoin` can join up to about 2,000 images in one operation. More than that and you'll need to assemble in stages.

You can download a Windows binary here:

https://github.com/jcupitt/libvips/releases

The docs for `arrayjoin` are here:

http://jcupitt.github.io/libvips/API/current/libvips-conversion.html#vips-arrayjoin

It has options for grid layout and alignment which might be useful.

Comment: Thx for your reply!!! I'm not a programmer so I'm looking for a ready-to-use-software solution. On the website of github I only found software to compile. Is there an (install) programm for windows to download which offers the functionality you described? Thx!

Comment: Hello, yes, go to the releases page I linked and download the windows zip. I suggest `vips-dev-w64-all-8.5.9.zip` from the list. Unzip it and you'll find `vips.exe` in the `bin` folder.

Answer (score 2):

Thx for your ideas!!! Finally I concatenated the pictures with vips, the main problem was actually displaying the picture since the first computer did't have enough RAM (16 GB). It always showed the final picture (with 86'400 x 21'600 pixels) with a black line at the bottom (like this https://ibb.co/bPGHnb)

To display the picture I used a computer with 32 GB RAM. Magick couldn't display it, since it couldn't allocate sufficient RAM. But [irfantview](http://www.irfanview.com/) finally made it.

Answer (score 1):

Your ImageMagick policy.xml file may allow you to create bigger images, if the limitation is not from PNG. See http://www.imagemagick.org/source/policy.xml

```
<policy domain="resource" name="width" value="10MP"/> 
<policy domain="resource" name="height" value="10MP"/> 
<policy domain="resource" name="area" value="100MP"/>
```

Use:

```
convert -list resource
```

to tell you what your current values are. For example, I get

```
convert -list resource
Resource limits:
  Width: 214.7MP
  Height: 214.7MP
  Area: 17.18GP
  Memory: 8GiB
  Map: 16GiB
  Disk: unlimited
  File: 192
  Thread: 4
  Throttle: 0
  Time: unlimited
```

But if you do not have enough RAM to hold that size resulting image and the input images. You may have to use the policy.xml file to map to disk, though that will be slower.

4*21600 = 86400. So you would need approximately 87 Mpixels wide on your width limitation.

Your area would need to be 8*21600*21600 = 3732480000 or about 3.7 Mpixels area.

Also 8images*24Bytes*21600*21600=89579520000 Bytes or about 90 GB, which needs to be doubled for both input and output data. I suspect that may be larger than your RAM amount.

Note that even though your PNGs are compressed, ImageMagick has to decompress them before processing.

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer.

Comment: I see your calculation of the RAM which is far away what I had available (tried it with two computers, one with 8 an other with 16GB RAM). I was able to concatenate the horizontal 1 x 4 lines to pictures of 86'400px x 21600px, but when i concatenated the two 86'400px x 21600px it failed on both computers but the result was the same. Approximately the last 10% of the horizontal lines in the pictures are black. So I guess the RAM is not the problem. Anyway I will check the policy  imagemagick and come back to you. Thx!

Comment: You may be running out ImageMagick tmp space on disk. Check your tmp directory where IM does its work. See MAGICK_TEMPORARY_PATH at http://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php#environment or /tmp on Unix-like systems

Comment: I checked the limitations by the command `convert -list resource` and this might be the problem. Checking the policy.xml-file (under C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\), i found other values then the command showed. E. g. the parameter width resulted in 214.748MP (command) and the file says `name="width" value="10MP"`
Why is that? So which values does the program really use? How can I modify them? And what is that file C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\policy.xml for?
Thx!!!

Comment: Uncomment any or all the lines you want to change and edit them as desired. The policy.xml file is to set limits and to avoid hacking through ImageMagick. So some of the lines are for security.

Comment: Originally my settings were: `Resource limits:
Width: 214.748MP, Height: 214.748MP, Area: 4.26894GP, Memory: 1.98788GiB, Map: 3.97576GiB, Disk: unlimited, File: 1536, Thread: 4, Throttle: 0, Time: unlimited`. Then I uncommented `<policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="8GiB"/>`, but typing `magick -list resources` still get `Memory: 1.98788GiB`. Why were the changed settings not applied?

Comment: What was the path to the file you edited? It is not the one in the download folder. You need to find where it is installed on your system and edit that one. See the list of possible paths at http://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php. Mine seems to be at /usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml. You are on IM 7, so look for it with ImageMagick-7 in the path.

Comment: I'm using Windows, so the path is C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\policy.xml I couldn't find any other policy.xlm file, so I don't understand why the settings are not applied.

Comment: Sorry, I am not a Windows user, so do not know the locations of files there. Did you reboot to see if that helped? Post this to http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/ where there are Windows users who can tell you how to find the right file.